# How can i access global variable using function in c++?

Tags: c++, global-variables, scope-resolution-operator

I want to access the value assigned to global variable in main function from the function. I don't want to pass argument in function.

I have tried referring different stack overflow similar questions and C++ libraries .

```
#include <iostream>

long s;  // global value declaration

void output()  // don't want to pass argument
{
    std::cout << s;
}

int main()
{
    long s;
    std::cin >> s;  // let it be 5
    output()
}
```

I expect the output to be `5` but it shows `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access  a global variable you should use of `::` sign before it :

```
long s = 5;          //global value definition

int main()
{
    long s = 1;              //local value definition
    cout << ::s << endl;     // output is 5
    cout << s << endl;       // output is 1
}
```

Also It's so simple to use global `s` in `cin` :

```
cin >> ::s;
cout << ::s << endl;
```

**Please [try it online](http://cpp.sh/6d5j7)**

Comment: can we do the same using function.

Comment: Yes we can do the same using a function,

Comment: i tried using it in function but it still returns 0.did you tried take the value of s using cin and then perform the same action.

Comment: @sahilarora How did you use it?

Comment: @sahilarora You obviously have to use it with the `cin` statement. The function is implicitely using the global variable already.

Comment: i took variable s from the input(cin) and displayed the value using function.

Comment: @sahilarora _"i took variable s from the input(cin)"_ As it was already mentioned the local variable `s` you have in `main()` is totally different from your global variable `::s`. So why would you expect the value of the input printed in your function?

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring another variable s in your main function. line 7 of your code. and it's the variable which is used in cin. either delete that line or use :: before s.

```
long s;
cin >> ::s; //let it be 5
output();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important for you to know that the local variable `s` declared in `main()` and the variable `s` declared at file scope aren't identical despite the name.

Since the local variable `s` declared in the function `main()` *shadows* (see [Scope - Name Hiding](https://en.cppreference.com/book/scope#Name_hiding)) the global variable `s` you have to use the [*Scope Resolution Operator* `::`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzarg/cplr175.htm) to access the global variable `s` declared at file-scope:

```
#include <iostream>

long s;

void output()
{
    std::cout << s;   // no scope resolution operator needed because there is no local
}                     // s in output() shadowing ::s

int main()
{
    long s;           // hides the global s
    std::cin >> ::s;  // qualify the hidden s
    output()
}
```

... or get rid of the local `s` in `main()`.

That said using global variables (without real need) is considered very bad practice. See [What’s the “static initialization order ‘fiasco’?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). While that doesn't affect [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)s it will bite you sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply and use:: before the global variable or just remove the

```
long s;
```

From main() because as you are declaring local variable s in the main() function. The Global s and local s are different despite having the same name. lets learn more by the following example by giving local and Global variable different name.

```
    #include <iostream>

long x;  // global value declaration

void output()  // don't want to pass argument
{
    std::cout << x;
}

int main()
{
    long s;
    std::cin >> s;  //here you are storing data on local variable s
    output() // But here you are calling global variable x. 
}
```

In main() function s is local and x is global variable and you are calling the global variable in output() function. you can use:: (scope resolution operator) for calling global x in main if u have the same naming or just call as it by variable name if they have a different name.

**PS:** *If you have any question just do comment down hope this will help you and understand what's the mistake. Read more about the scope of the local and global variable [here](https://funprogramming.org/50-What-are-global-and-local-variables.html)*

Answer (score 0):

You defined output() on the global scope which means it will refer to the long s variable on the global scope not the long s defined in main().

Answer (score -1):

First of all, when you declare a global variable without assigning a value it automatically sets it's value to 0.

And another thing, you should know about your scope. The variable s in your main function has no existence in the output function.

In the output function , you are getting 0 because your global variable is set to 0.

You can just change you global variable's value by assigning different value to it.

```
long s; //global value declaration
void output() //don't want to pass argument
{
   cout<<s;  
}
int main()
{
   cin>>s; //let it be 5
   output()
}
```